# Best way to store page offset value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

What would be the best way/recommended pattern to store and show page offset value changing by scroll events?

1. store values in `useState`

```js
function App() {

  const [posY, setPosY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e) => setPosY(window.pageYOffset);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });

  return <div>{posY}</div>;
}
```

2. store values in `useRef`

```js
function App() {

  const posYRef = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e) => {posYRef.current = window.pageYOffset};
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });

  return <div>{posYRef.current}</div>;
}
```

3. directly access and write to innerHTML (well... I'm kinda serious)

```js
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e) => {
      document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = window.pageYOffset;
    );
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  });

  return <div>{0}</div>;
}
```

I understand that #1 is usually regarded as the correct execution, but I want to know if #2 or #3 is necessarily bad in this case. Can we *practically* do #2 or #3 as they just work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research for a while, I concluded all above three could work in exceptional situations although #1 is definitely the standard/recommended way.

While I agree that `state` should be used for most cases to get proper updates on React renders, #2 or #3 works as well *if the page never updates after it is loaded*. It works especially when non-React supporting third party libraries are manipulating DOMs, and you need to update them using React. It is React anti-pattern and could potentially create maintenance hell, so you should know what you are doing when doing #2 or #3.

Regarding performance, #2 or #3 should be even faster in theory as both skip virtual DOM updates. However, in normal situation, it made little difference when manipulating a couple of hundred DOM elements; which means using #2 or #3 cannot be justified with better rendering performance in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the state for this, as you want to show animation on the basis of the scroll, you should update the state, and that state change would trigger re-render on react.
While setting innerHTML wouldn't do the re-render.